# Pandas return True if condition True in any of previous n rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

example df:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9],[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9],[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])


    a   b   c   
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3   1   2   3
4   4   5   6
5   7   8   9
6   1   2   3
7   4   5   6
8   7   8   9
```

Goal is to get a new column, 'd', that returns True when a certain condition is true anywhere within a rolling window of size n.
For example, desired column 'd' for condition "column c == 2 within rolling window of 2":

```
    a   b   c   d  
0   1   2   3   nan
1   4   5   6   True
2   7   8   9   False
3   1   2   3   True
4   4   5   6   True
5   7   8   9   False
6   1   2   3   True
7   4   5   6   True
8   7   8   9   False
```

I hope my question is understood thank you for taking your time
To be clear, I am trying to return True if ANY of the rows in the rolling window return True

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you meant column **b**:

```
s = df2['b'].eq(2).rolling(2).max()
df2['d'] = s.astype(bool).mask(s.isna())
```

*NB. you need to use `max` as `rolling` only works with numeric data.*

Output:

```
   a  b  c      d
0  1  2  3    NaN
1  4  5  6   True
2  7  8  9  False
3  1  2  3   True
4  4  5  6   True
5  7  8  9  False
6  1  2  3   True
7  4  5  6   True
8  7  8  9  False
```